# execute commands with options in a c program

Tags: c, command, argv, execvp

I'm trying to execute a commande with arguments in a c program.
For example when the user execute my program with:
"./a.out ls -la"

The program should execute ls with the la options.

But I don't know how to do that.

My program use a fork.

I try this way :

```
pid = fork();

if(pid == 0){

execvp(argv[1], &argv[2]);

}else{

wait(NULL);

}
```

But it does not work.

I want to pass as a second argument of execvp the array with the args passing in the command but i'm a little confuse with pointers (and so more with pointer of pointers :s) .

I know this souldn't work because of the dash in arguments but even if I don't use the dash, the program only launch the 'ls' without taking care of the 'la' options.

If someone could help me I would be happy to know the good way to do.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several problems here.

1. you do not handle the case where `fork()` fails.
2. you do not handle the case where `execvp()` fails.  If you print `strerror(errno)` it might give you a clue as to why your exec is failing.
3. [execvp()](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl3_execvp.htm) takes an array of `char* const` which must have `NULL` as its last element.  Also, the first element should be the name of the program. This is a convention, but it does mean that, in your example the arguments are off by one. i.e. `ls` thinks it  has been invoked with a command of `-la` and no arguments.  I'm not sure that `argv[]` is guaranteed to have a `NULL` pointer after the end, so don't use it directly. e.g.

   ```
   char* args[3];
   args[0] = argv[1]; // You have already checked argc is at least three right?
   args[1] = argv[2];
   args[2] = NULL;
   // do your fork and error check then in the child

   int result = execvp(argv[1], args);
   // if you get here exec failed, handle as appropriate
   ```
4. You need to check the exit valueof `wait()` and you should pass a legitimate `int` pointer so that you can diagnose any issues.

Answer (score 1):

`system`

Quoth Wikipedia:

> In the C standard library, system is a function used to execute subprocesses and commands. It is defined in stdlib.h header. It differs from the exec/spawn family of functions in that instead of passing arguments to an executed object, a single string is passed to the system shell, typically the POSIX shell, /bin/sh -c.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_(C_standard_library)

Comment: Don't use `system()`, it's rubbish.  The proper way is to use fork and exec.